# File Not Found Exception in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, windows, exception, windows-10-universal

Plase, help me, I have the following line of code in C# inside some async method and I use Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393):

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/HamburgerMenuItems.json"));
```

The problem is this exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll.

Visual Studio shows me, that the file is inside the Assets folder and the file is ok, because it opens normally (it is very short json file). What can be the problem or what is solution for this problem?

[this image shows, that the file is inside the Assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfxax.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `BuildAction` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` from `Do not copy` to `Awayls`.

[image]