# c# Local Application edit app without recompiling/reinstallation

Tags: c#, uwp, web-config

I am using Windows UWP C# to create a desktop application. Currently, I am creating the app package this way..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

However, I may need to edit the API endpoints in the future after the application has been installed. Is there a file (such as web config) that is referenced which doesn't require another installation after being edited?

*NOTE: This question is different than the "duplicate" question, [ConfigurationManager and AppSettings in universal (UWP) app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34803648), because I do not want to reinstall the app. The "duplicate" question does not require recompiling, but it would need to create a new app.

Comment: Where are you saving your API endpoints?

Comment: You could create a file in your [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData) folders either in the Local, Remote, or Publisher folders.  If a file doesn't exist when your application starts, you write the current endpoints to the file.

Then if you have an update, as long as you have a more stable location to grab the new endpoints from, you could download the new info and update the file.

You would also want to encrypt the file to prevent tampering though.

Comment: @PaulKaram Currently saving them in my web.config file.

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT If I'm understanding correctly -- The application will grab data from a static reference point that is not associated with the build. So the application will grab information from an endpoint (or file location)  that will never change.

Comment: @Mocha and don't you have access to that file where the application is being installed?

Comment: @PaulKaram I do, but when I "store" the application, the web.config file disappears.