# Is there a web.config equivalent for UWP App development?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

In web development we have web.config where I can manually configure a few app settings for each client separately. Is there a similar thing for UWP apps [I am developing a Windows UWP app.]

Comment: All what you need here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track

Comment: Where will I find the external file (eg: settings.xml) once I install the app on client device.. any idea?

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803648/configurationmanager-and-appsettings-in-universal-uwp-app

Comment: in uwp for windows application there is **App.xaml** file in which you can configure application settings.even in app.xaml file you can catch the application start resume ideal close event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, it helps you.

You can add `appsettings.json` file
e.g.:-

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

Make sure that appsettings.json file property set "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy always".

Find Values from `appsettings.json` file like this-

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
string GetValue1 = configuration.GetSection("key1").Value;
string GetValue2 = configuration.GetSection("key2").Value;
```

Thanks!!!